# Can I track Tags I have created?

Tags: discussion, tags

Question is in the title I guess. Is there any way to know which tags your user profile created? Out of interest more than anything, but wasn't aware of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really; see [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10888/145982) on the main meta. As [the accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10888/how-does-one-find-which-tags-they-created/10898#10898) says:

> `Tag -> sort by newest -> last page -> question on the bottom`, should be the earliest question asked with that tag, but still not guaranteed that that question or that user created the tag.

The information is maintained for badge purposes, but it's not shown anywhere

Comment: Thanks. It is probably a good thing, so people do not try to inflate the use of their own tags. I know I created some, I just don't know which ones!

Comment: Sooner or later Wikileaks will reveal every people's votes on SE sites. It just has more pressing issues right now.